# How to useEffect in component that is rendered in another component

Tags: reactjs, svg.js

This is what I am trying to do:

```
import { SVG } from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'

const SVGpaper = (props) => {

  useEffect(() => {
    let canvas = SVG().addTo('#canvas').size(6006, 600);
    canvas.rect(100, 100);
  });

  return (
    <div id="canvas">

    </div>
  )
}

const Profile = () => {
    return (
     (typeof someVariable !== "undefined") &&
        <CCol>
            <CRow>
                <div>
                {SVGpaper()}
                </div>
            </CRow>
        </CCol>

    );



};
export default Profile;
```

Profile is the "big" webpage, it will fetch some data from a server to "someVariable". To make sure it is not rendered prematurely it (Profile) has conditional rendering. When it is eventually rendered I want to create an SVG. I have therefore created a component that creates the SVG and put it into the render of Profile. Because SVG().addTo must be executed after the div id="canvas" actually exist, it is put in a useEffect to prevent it from executing before the div exist. This works great in my head, but not in reality because it breaks the rules of hooks. I get the error:

"Warning: React has detected a change in the order of Hooks called by Profile. This will lead to bugs and errors if not fixed. For more information, read the Rules of Hooks: [https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks"](https://reactjs.org/link/rules-of-hooks%22)

And I should know this, but I am having issues making this code work, so I am trying a little bit of every idea I get, but without any success. How can I change this code and make it render in this order:

1. conditional rendering for "someVariable"
2. render the div with id="canvas"
3. Create the SVG and assign it to the div with id="canvas"
   ?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `{SVGpaper()}` - this is no how you use components. Should be `<SVGPaper />`

Comment: Ohhhh, now it works! But it is called multiple times so I get multiple SVGs. Do you know how to only run it once?

Comment: Never mind, gave useEffect an empty array and now it works. I though giving it nothing as a second argument defaulted to an empty array but apparently not. Now it works :)

Comment: Passing nothing as a second argument to `useEffect` makes it run every render